# How to wrap the middle div down

Tags: css

The code below have three divs that expected to be responsive based on how the user resize the window.

when the window is too small, i want the middle div to wrap down like the picture explain.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #mainCont
        {
            background-color: lightblue;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }#middleCont
        {
            background-color: lavender;
        }#middleCont a
        {
            padding: 0 80px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainCont">
        <div>Word</div>
        <div id="middleCont">
            <a href="#">link 1</a>
            <a href="#">link 2</a>
            <a href="#">link 3</a>
            <a href="#">link 4</a>
            <a href="#">link 5</a>
        </div>
        <div>Word</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN02X.jpg)

Thanks

The expected result explained in the picture

Comment: If someone need more info please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using **order** css property we can change the order of elements based on screen size and use flex-wrap to make another row
> [DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)
>
> It is best practice to use class name selector instead of id selector

```css
.mainCont
        {
            background-color: lightblue;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .middleCont
        {
            background-color: lavender;
        }
        .middleCont a
        {
            padding: 0 80px;
        }

@media (max-width: 575.98px){
  .mainCont{
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
  .middleCont{
    order:3
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mainCont">
        <div>Word</div>
        <div class="middleCont">
            <a href="#">link 1</a>
            <a href="#">link 2</a>
            <a href="#">link 3</a>
            <a href="#">link 4</a>
            <a href="#">link 5</a>
        </div>
        <div>Word</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Yuvaraj, been struggling with almost the whole day try to figure it out myself.

Comment: its okay, happy coding